# Android radius button

Tags: java, android, xml, button

I have a button like this

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="ButtonText"
    style="@style/ButtonText"/>
```

and this style

```
<style name="ButtonText">
    <item name="android:layout_margin">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">2</item>
</style>
```

Now I want to add radius to button, I have tried `<item name="android:radius">6dp</item>` but it is not working. What is a solution for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe to add radius to a button you have to create a custom drawable (see this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape), specifically the shape drawable section)

then, with the drawable defined, set the `background` xml tag of the button equal to your drawable file:

`android:background="@drawable/your_file"`

Answer (score 8):

In your drawable folder, create a round_button.xml with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- http://www.dibbus.com/2011/02/gradient-buttons-for-android/ -->
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>

            <corners
                android:radius="2dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

and then in the xml containing the button, set the background as:

`android:background="@drawable/round_button"`

Comment: `android:background="@drawable/round_button"`